2 animation tracks wont play at the same time. (Godot 4.2.2)
I’m new to Godot so this is probably a stupid question, but I’m trying to make a moving platform move and also rotate like it’s floating on water, but it only plays one of my animation/rotation tracks. If I disable a track then re-enable it, the other track will work, and the one I just re-enabled wont work. (Both tracks play in the animation editor thingy, but when I load the game only one plays. Yes, Autoplay on Load is turned on. I'm also sure there are no scripts interfering with the movement.)
